# Iterating through list of lists of lists

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, iteration

I am trying to iterate through a 3-D list in python(not numpy but I am willing to convert to a numpy array if this makes it easier) in such a way that from a list like this:

```
a = [[[0, 0], [3, 0]], [[1, 0], [4, 0]], [[2, 0], [6, 0]] ]
```

I can get the output

```
[0,0]
[1,0]
[2,0]
[3,0]
[4,0]
[6,0]
```

I can't figure out how to make it iterate like this...

My code:

```
a = [[[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[1, 0], [0, 0]], [[2, 0], [0, 0]] ]
for i in range(len(a)):
    for z in range(len(a[i])):
        print(a[i][z])
```

I've tried different things but can't seem to get this output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to print the nth sub-sublists consecutively from each sublist. You could unpack and zip `a` to get an iterable of tuples, then print each pair in them:

```
for tpl in zip(*a):
    for pair in tpl:
        print(pair)
```

Output:

```
[0, 0]
[1, 0]
[2, 0]
[3, 0]
[4, 0]
[6, 0]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```py
print(*[i for v in zip(*a) for i in v], sep="\n")
```

Prints:

```py
[0, 0]
[1, 0]
[2, 0]
[3, 0]
[4, 0]
[6, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to just traverse the elements column wise, you can convert the list to numpy array, then stack the columns and print:

```
import numpy as np
a = [[[0, 0], [3, 0]], [[1, 0], [4, 0]], [[2, 0], [6, 0]] ]
arr = np.stack(np.array(a), axis=1)

for p in arr:
    for x in p:
        print(x)
```

The solution below is based on the previous assumption of printing each item in the sublist based on sorted order:
You can use itertools to flatten the 3d to 2d list and then sort the 2d list based on first element in each sublist. Then print the sorted list.

```
import itertools
a = [[[0, 0], [3, 0]],[[1, 0], [4, 0]],[[2, 0], [6, 0]]]
flat_list = list(itertools.chain(*a))
sorted_list = sorted(flat_list, key=lambda x: x[0])

for i in sorted_list:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way of iterating like you're trying to do:

```
a = [[[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[1, 0], [0, 0]], [[2, 0], [0, 0]] ]
for i in range(len(a)):
    for z in range(len(a[i])):
        print((a[i])[z])
```

If it is simpler for you, instead of iterating on the length of the lists with an index, try iterating on the elements of the lists:

```
a = [[[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[1, 0], [0, 0]], [[2, 0], [0, 0]] ]
for a1 in a:
    for a2 in a1:
        print(a2)
```

Comment: This doesn't give the output OP wants.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi you're correct, it was not clear to me at the beginning.